# What's the meaning of the error value 0x16f returned by the GetLastError() function

Tags: windows, winapi, createprocess, createprocessasuser, getlasterror

When I call the function `CreateProcessAsUser()`, it returns a failure.
And then the call to `GetLastError()` to check why the error occurred returns the value 0x16f.

I couldn't find out what the error is supposed to mean.

Comment: The first stop for error codes is `net helpmsg`.  In this case `net helpmsg 367` returns "The process creation has been blocked."  Not very clear, unfortunately, and Googling doesn't turn up much.  Possibly caused by anti-virus software deciding your child process is malicious?  Or your process is assigned to a job object with restrictions preventing you from launching a child process?  Or perhaps something to do with the Windows Store sandbox?  (We might be able to help more if you can explain the circumstances in which the error occurred.)

Comment: Some highlighting, some spelling fixes, and some improvement of grammar (I hope).

Answer (score 2):

`ERROR_CHILD_PROCESS_BLOCKED` is converted `NTSTATUS` - `STATUS_CHILD_PROCESS_BLOCKED` (`0xC000049D`) - I search in `ntoskrnl.exe` and found that this code referenced only from 2 place when `NtCreateUserProcess` called - from `SeSubProcessToken` and for log error:

```
NtCreateUserProcess
  PspAllocateProcess
    PspInitializeProcessSecurity
      SeSubProcessToken
        if (!SeTokenIsNoChildProcessRestricted(Token))
        {
            status = STATUS_CHILD_PROCESS_BLOCKED;
        }


  if (PspAllocateProcess() == STATUS_CHILD_PROCESS_BLOCKED)
  {
    EtwTraceDeniedTokenCreation();
  }
```

so when `SeTokenIsNoChildProcessRestricted(Token)` return `FALSE` you can got `ERROR_CHILD_PROCESS_BLOCKED` from `CreateProcess`.

this is new api, exist only from 1607 build of win10

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN10_RS1)
NTKERNELAPI
BOOLEAN
SeTokenIsNoChildProcessRestricted(
    _In_ PACCESS_TOKEN Token
    );// return (Token->TokenFlags & 0x80000) != 0;
#endif
```

declared in `ntifs.h` but not documented.

so process, which fail call `CreateProcessAsUser` is somehow restricted. Windows Store sandbox , as how Harry Johnston guess ?